# Powershell - stopping after specific cell when retrieving from JSON

Tags: json, powershell, rest, cell

I'm trying to retrieve cell contents from a JSON output using powershell. The table has a total of 32 cells as shown with the results from my request using API Tester. Each line is made of 8 columns.
For a reason I don't understand, when I try to extract the value from a specific cell using $details.Data.CustomFieds[24].Cells[x], where x goes from 0 to 7, PowerShell return some contents, but without values. However, again using the API tester, I can see values are not null.
Moreover, starting from cell 8, nothing is returned.

Any hint ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the json?

Comment: `.Cells[x]` makes me think you are talking about an Excel file rather than JSON.. PLease show us what you have to deal with, so we can (hopefully) answer.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) example.